# numpy dot product of sub array?

Tags: numpy, numpy-einsum

I have two ndarray like

```
n1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
n2 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

While dot product of them can done easily with `np.dot(n1, n2)`, which gives 30 as the right answer. What if I need the dot to be operated on two subarrays from n1 and n2, e.g.

```
np.dot(np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2]))  # first two elements from arrays
np.dot(np.array([3,4]), np.array([3,4]))  # last two elements
```

Gives [5, 25]. I could do it by hand split array and for loop. But wondering if there is a more pythonic and numpy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
In [124]: n1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
     ...: n2 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
     ...:
```

reshaping splits the arrays in to the desired blocks:

```
In [125]: n1.reshape(2,2)
Out[125]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

now multiply all elements together - and sum on the right axis (sometimes I guess as to axis).

```
In [126]: (n1.reshape(2,2)*n2.reshape(2,2)).sum(axis=1)
Out[126]: array([ 5, 25])
```

That sum of products can also be expressed with `einsum` - but don't worry if the syntax is too new:

```
In [127]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',n1.reshape(2,2), n2.reshape(2,2))
Out[127]: array([ 5, 25])
```

Answer (score 2):

Reshape to have two two column arrays, since we want subarrays of length `2` each and then use `np.einsum` for the sum-reduction -

```
a = n1.reshape(-1,2)
b = n2.reshape(-1,2)

out = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)
```

Another one would be to do element-wise multiplication, then use one reshape and finally sum each row for a compact solution -

```
out = (n1*n2).reshape(-1,2).sum(1) # 2 is subarray length
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! As only one answer can be accpeted, I've to choose hpaulj's answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the dot by manually multiplying and adding the arrays. If you use [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)'s [`reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method, you have the flexibility of summing over completely arbitrary intervals:

```
n = np.add.reduceat(n1 * n2, [0, 2])
```

If you wanted to have the sum over the first three and the last one element, you would just pass `[0, 3]` for the indices (the second argument).

If arbitrary length intervals are not interesting to you, use the other answers instead.

Comment: Just to make it generic : `np.arange(0,n1.size,2)` for the indices.

Comment: @divakar. At that point, I think your answer will be better. Mine is only necessary if the intervals are uneven.

Comment: True if subarrays are of arbitrary lengths.